# ios puzzle app crashes after a few rounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have an iPhone app, that seems to have memory leaking problem. It's a puzzle game, after a few puzzles, the app crashes on devices.

I'm now trying to use xcode Instruments to detect what's going on. First time to use Instruments.

I noticed a leak bar in the "Leaks" plot, right the time when the view is loaded:
[What are these memory leaking objects, detected by xCode Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749936/what-are-these-memory-leaking-objects-detected-by-xcode-instruments?noredirect=1#comment29348285_19749936)
. However these leaked objects are small, so I guess my app has other problems.

When my app continues to run, usually for 10+ rounds on an iPad 2, it then crashes. I don't much about Instruments yet, so I watch "All Heap Allocations". At the beginning of first round puzzle, the column "# Overall" is ~70k, it grows slowly between rounds of puzzles. When a new round puzzle comes in, it goes to ~90k, then round by round it reaches ~200k, then crashes.

Before crashes, in the log console I see memory warning and "CONNECTION INTERRUPTED".

I've followed a few things after searching memory leaking, such set NSArray/NSDictionary or mutable ones to nil, as much as possible (although not all of them, since some go between puzzles). I also changed UIImage imageNamed to [UIIMage alloc] initWithContentOfFile.

What else should I look/check to see what causes memory problem? TIA!

EDIT:
I wish I could post some codes that may be the suspect, but I really don't know what part to post. I should've check via Instruments in the course developing, so that I would know what caused the problem.

Regarding other view controllers. I do have others (menu, settings, app-store-rate, etc) and I generated all of them via code. My app doesn't have a storyboard or nib file. When I test crashes, I just click Next Puzzle button, so all other views will not show at all. So, before crash, the only view shown is the main view, with a few button, a few subviews, an animated pictures (but only the first puzzle as introduction). If it helps, here is my app:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wordsect/id599455449?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: It's hard to advise you without knowing more about your app. Do you have multiple view controllers? How are you moving between them? When you start a new round, are you starting "fresh" with new controllers? Are the old ones deallocated?

Comment: Also posting some codes which have issues with might help brother.

Comment: @rdelmar, I added a few lines in my original post, so others can see it. thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Next Puzzle button? Also, when you go to the next puzzle, is the previous puzzle deleted and removed from memory?

Comment: adding now, still to the original post. thanks.

Comment: What about the setupStage method? In addition to rdelmar's tip any place you create views or add assets is a good place to look.

Comment: Another place to look at would be all the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` implementations. Maybe one of them is failing?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to debug application with Instruments - enable zombie detection mode:

In

1. Xcode: Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme
2. Select Debug scheme
3. Select Arguments tab bar on the scheme description
4. In Environments variables add and check NSZombieEnabled variable

Then when you start application under Instruments control, you'll get name of the instance, when your application crashed.